# Splitting a Single Database Field into Multiple Fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

The following is a query written to split the following tables. The third column is suffix, and the column before this field will not trim the -suffix off the end of the returned field. I have attached the query as well as an image of the results and the issue.

```
SELECT Left([ADDRESS_ID],InStr([ADDRESS_ID],"-")-1) AS Abbreviation,
       Mid([ADDRESS_ID],InStr([ADDRESS_ID],"-")+1) AS CODE,
       Right([ADDRESS_ID],InStr([ADDRESS_ID],"-")) AS SUFFIX,
       MDM_Address_Remote_Key.ADDRESS_ID
FROM MDM_Address_Remote_Key;
```

The three columns are broken apart and should look like the third; however, the middle column is holding onto the suffix at the end. How to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `mid` function expects 3 parameters:

```
Mid ( text, start_position, number_of_characters )
```

If you don't specify the last parameter, the `mid` function will return all characters after the start_position, which lead to your result.

Try:

```
Mid([ADDRESS_ID],InStr([ADDRESS_ID],"-")+1,InStrRev([ADDRESS_ID],"-")-(InStr([ADDRESS_ID],"-")+1)) AS CODE
```

Comment: @MR: In addition, you also should use `InStrRev` for the SUFFIX part. Currently it is only by luck (the first "-" always being at position 2) that this part works.

Answer (score 1):

This expression extracts the substring I think you want for `CODE`:

```sql
Mid([ADDRESS_ID], InStr(1, [ADDRESS_ID], "-") + 1, InStrRev([ADDRESS_ID], "-") - InStr(1, [ADDRESS_ID], "-") - 1) AS CODE
```

However, that expression is rather complex, and your other field expressions are already fairly complex --- whole lotta functions going on.

If you will be running the query from within an Access session, you could use a custom function which leverages the VBA `Split()` function.

Then your query could be simpler and clear.

```sql
SELECT SplitSegment([ADDRESS_ID], "-", 0) AS Abbreviation,
       SplitSegment([ADDRESS_ID], "-", 1) AS CODE,
       SplitSegment([ADDRESS_ID], "-", 2) AS SUFFIX,
       MDM_Address_Remote_Key.ADDRESS_ID
FROM MDM_Address_Remote_Key;
```

```vb
Public Function SplitSegment(ByVal pSource As Variant, _
        ByVal pDelimter As String, _
        ByVal pIndex As Long) As Variant

    Dim varOut As Variant
    varOut = Null
    If Not IsNull(pSource) Then
        varOut = Split(pSource, pDelimter)(pIndex)
    End If
    SplitSegment = varOut
End Function
```